# Net Core Simple way to Find Temperature from Openweather API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, console, asp.net-core-2.0

I just started programming. What is a simple way to grab the temperature and display it on screen?  I want to write a simple program.

```
static void Main()
{

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org");
    var response = client.GetAsync($"/data/2.5/weather?q=London,UK&appid={APIKey}&units=metric");

    // What do I place here??


    Console.WriteLine(Main.Temp);


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 concepts you need to consider here:

### Asynchronous programming

`HttpClient.GetAsync()` is an asynchronous method. There is a nice walk-through of working with async APIs in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

But the gist of it is that method doesn't return the data from the endpoint. It returns a "promise"; something that represents the data that will be available at a future time. Since your program isn't doing any other things, you can just `await` the result, like so:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync();
```

But of course, you need to first make the enclosing method `async`. In your case, change the signature of your `Main()` function to:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
```

### JSON Deserialization

The endpoint you're calling returns its data in [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format. Since you're just learning, I wouldn't bother trying to find an actual schema or client library.

What you should do instead is to create a class with properties for each of the fields in the response, and deserialize into it, as shown here:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: Whats the final code base look like, are you able to display as a template? Thanks,

Comment: thank you, can you thumbs up my question and answer below also? just accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

Using answer from John:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static async Task Main()
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org");
            var response = await client.GetAsync($"/data/2.5/weather?q=London,UK&appid=c44d8aa0c5e588db11ac6191c0bc6a60");

            // This line gives me error
            var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(stringResult);
            var tmpDegreesF = Math.Round(((float)obj.main.temp * 9 / 5 - 459.67),2) ;
            Console.WriteLine($"Current temperature is {tmpDegreesF}°F");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

     }
}
```

Locate something similar to netcoreapp2.1
Under this line, add 7.1 - this will instruct VS and the compiler to check your code/compile your code against C# 7.1 rules

Update: What I read also from above, I can either create JSON classes to represent  data (the easiest way is to use the Edit | Paste Special menu), or deserialize to dynamic.