# Net Core Solving "Does Not Contain a Definition for Content Error" and Read as String in API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, console, asp.net-core-2.0

I keep receiving an error below. One way to solve is move the code into a Controller. If I do not want to place in controller, and create a simple console app, how would I go about removing error below, while Read as String?

```
    static void Main()
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org");
        var response = client.GetAsync($"/data/2.5/weather?q=London,UK&appid=c44d8aa0c5e588db11ac6191c0bc6a60&units=metric");

        // This line gives me error
        var stringResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**Error:** Does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no accessible extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Net Core Simple way to Find Temperature from Openweather API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436226/net-core-simple-way-to-find-temperature-from-openweather-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async methods return `Task` objects. The IDE is correct to tell you that `Task` does not contain a definition for `Content`.

You should `await` the tasks by changing your code to be like this:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync($"/data/2.5/weather?q=London,UK&appid=c44d8aa0c5e588db11ac6191c0bc6a60&units=metric");
var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

`Await` will wait for the task to complete (important) and unbox the result (i.e. unwrap it from the `Task` object).

Next, your problem is that `static void Main()` isn't an `async` method so the `await` keyword isn't valid. You can resolve this by doing the following:

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click your project and select "Edit NAME.csproj"
2. Locate something similar to `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>`
3. Under this line, add `<LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>` - this will instruct VS and the compiler to check your code/compile your code against C# 7.1 rules ([the earliest language version that added async Main methods](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/)).
4. Change your `Main()` signature to `static async Task Main()`

Final code:

```
static async Task Main()
{

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org");
    var response = await client.GetAsync($"/data/2.5/weather?q=London,UK&appid=c44d8aa0c5e588db11ac6191c0bc6a60&units=metric");

    // This line gives me error
    var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  
}
```

Comment: The `async` main method is great .

Comment: @itminus Indeed :-)

Comment: dang man, how long have you been programming and how did you figure this out? great, also had a question here, if you know final code base https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436226/net-core-simple-way-to-find-temperature-from-openweather-api

Comment: @CarSpeed From beginning to teach myself as a kid, 18 years. Professionally for about 7. As for your other question, you can either create JSON classes to represent your data (the easiest way is to use the Edit | Paste Special menu), or deserialize to `dynamic`. For example: `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(stringResult); var tmpDegreesC = ((double)obj.main.temp)-273; Console.WriteLine($"Current temperature is {tmpDegreesC}°C");`